# Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library - Deprecated

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I'am following the Stop watch demo from Google 2013 IO
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmv1dTnhLH4&feature=player_detailpage#t=2225

I try to generate App Engine Backend but failed, it says I need to install "Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library" but it is Deprecated!. What do I use?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Messaging is now included in the Play Services SDK.

Have a look: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this package is now obsolete. In order to see it in SDK Manager I had to check "Show obsolete packages" in the "Packages" menu

**Edit (clarification of my answer)**

I encountered this problem when trying to run `Maven Android SDK Deployer`. The version of the SDK deployer I used, was expecting gcm package installed (at least when running the deployer in  its default configuration).

For other purposes, it's recommended to use the newer `Google Play Services` instead, as stated in one of the answers here.[image]